# File path error in Angular 2

Tags: angular, primeng

I am trying to implement PrimeNG datatable, I have data in a JSON file called `cars-small.json`, I think the path is correct in the code, I checked almost 20 times and also checked it by changing the name of it and path of that file but always get 404 error.

This is how I am trying to get it:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class CarService {

datatable = "app/services/cars-small.json";
url = this.datatable;

constructor(private http: Http) {}

getCarsSmall() {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
                .toPromise()
                .then(res => <Car[]> res.json().data)
                .then(data => { return data; });
    }
}
```

But always get 404 error, check this error image (https://imgur.com/StSFhUP) and actual image path (https://imgur.com/cxEHMJ6).

Comment: both shows same image

Comment: sorry, i update it check now

Comment: Make sure that the json file is added to the webpack static files list.

Comment: how? i have no idea about it

Comment: add the path to the file in the assets section of the `angular-cli.json` file

Comment: only name or with full path?

Comment: I believe it is the full path relative to the location of the `angular-cli.json` file

Comment: @Teddy Sterne not work :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the datatable as follows, Since app refers to the folder where the application is in,

```
datatable = "/services/cars-small.json";
```

**EDIT**

Since you are making a http.get, it should have a full path like, `http://localhost:4200/services/cars-small.json`

Copy the json file to the assets folder `**src/assets/cars-small.json**` and then you should be able to access it

```
datatable = "/assets/cars-small.json";
```

Comment: cannot be, can you paste in url and see if it loads

Comment: @MuhammadArslan Angular 2 uses relative pathing, you need to use something like `./cars-small.json`

Comment: @MuhammadArslan did you try it in browser?

Comment: @MuhammadArslan See my edited comment, I made a minor mistake in your service location.

Comment: @Sajeetharan i tried it, bu it take me back to localhost:4200

Comment: @MuhammadArslan Also, you're requesting by HTTP, therefore you need to include the hostname in your get. This means the full HTTP path of `http://localhost:4200/services/cars-small.json`

Comment: @MuhammadArslan yes if you are loading through a get it should be http://localhost:4200/services/cars-small.json

Comment: @Sajeetharan file is not displaying in browser

Comment: do you have a team viewer?

Comment: @Sajeetharan yes i have

Comment: share the id here can login and check

Comment: here it is 564 949 930

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139303/discussion-between-muhammad-arslan-and-sajeetharan).

Answer (score 1):

Since the app folder is not public so put your `cars-small.json` into `src/assets/cars-small.json` and the you can access with url something like

`http://localhost:4200/assets/cars-small.json`

Remember except assets folder no other folder is public you have to put all your mock data inside it like your other static files images etc

Comment: @Arsalan checkout the second answer it'll solve your problem i already did something like this

Comment: so i need to put every json file in asset folder?

Comment: Yes every static file should be in assets folder